# Import Excel data in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table in my Access application which needs to be filled with data in a bunch of Excel files. I tried this code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, strTable, strExcelpath, True
```

But it overwrite the data in my access table each time instead of appending it and it gives absolutely no control over what is being sent.

I need to find a way to simply append the data from an Excel file to my Access table, both files have the same structure so I would like to know if there is a way to import it line by line without specifying the columns. However, for personal knowledge and fear of user uses, I would also like to know how to import it considering the lines and columns.

Thanks !

EDIT: Code with the select on the Excel file:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strQuery As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Excel\test.xls;" & _
                        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

strQuery = "INSERT INTO tblClients " & _
        "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE =" & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Excel\test.xls].[tblImport$]"
DoCmd.RunSQL strQuery
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also refer to an Excel sheet or range in a query:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ( ADate ) 
SELECT SomeDate FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$a1:a4]
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$]
```

In a procedure:

```
Sub RunThisQuery()
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO tblClients " & _
       "SELECT * FROM [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=" _
       & Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Excel\test.xls].[tblImport$]"

    CurrentDB.Execute strQuery, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```

Note that you had a space in your code after `DATABASE`. It must read `DATABASE=`, no space.

Comment: Consider that my Excel files currently have close to 200 columns... Could I do a SELECT * ? Is there any doc for this part [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=Z:\Docs\Test.xls].[Sheet1$a1:a4]
Thanks !

Comment: Yes, you can use * as long as the order is the same, but it is never recommended. You will get some info here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819, and a lot more in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Where are you running the query? the above is intended for the query design window. You should post your code as modified to suit your application.

Comment: Almost none of that is necessary. I will post above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15067/discussion-between-estarius-and-remou)