# How to import multiple Excel files into an Access table with an extra column indicating Excel file name using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to import two excel files (Book1.xlsx and Book2.xlsx) into an access database table (Table1), with an extra column indicating the data source:

1.xlsx

```
Name    Age
Paul    30
```

2.xlsx

```
Name    Age
John    20
```

Table1

```
Name    Age Source
Paul    30  Book1
John    20  Book2
```

What would be the best way to automate this via either Access VBA or Excel VBA?
I will have dozens of excel files with each file containing around 50K rows.

Do I have to open every excel file to run an Excel VBA macro to insert records line-by-line using ADODB? If so, how should I write the macro?

But ideally I want to do it in Access VBA macro. I can use "DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet" to import two Excel files into the table, but I don't know how to add the additional "Source" column inside the VBA.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You couls use a macro to add the filename column to each file, then import using `TransferSpreadsheet`

Answer (score 0):

You can do an `insert into ... select ...` query against Excel spreadsheets as if they were Access database tables. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11866465/20371 for details.

You can adapt the code shown in the above to work with a collection of files--say, all files in a folder. And since you're doing it as a query, you can easily add a `Source` column and set its value to the file name or whatever.

My only warning with this method would be to carefully convert data types when selecting and inserting them from a spreadsheet. By this I mean wrap decimal numbers with `cdbl(num)`, integers with `cint(num)`, strings with `cstr(str)`, etc. And if you do any logical comparisons with the data in the query, then account for missing values. So instead of:

```
insert into ...
select ...
from ...
where x = 1
```

do:

```
insert into ...
select ...
from ...
where iif(x is null, 0, x) = 1
```